# unable to install django restframework.auth_token

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Trying to install from source

```
git clone https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework.git
cd django-rest-framework
setup.py install
```

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
...
        'rest_framework.authtoken',
        'rest_framework',
...
)
```

Trying to migrate

manage.py migrate

```
    WindowsError: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 
   'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\djangorestframework-3.0.0-py2.7.egg\\rest_framework\\authtoken\\migrations/*.*'
```

Whats the problem here ? Why is this a windows error ?

(rest_framework is migrating just fine ... )

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up copying the actual folder i cloned into `c:\Python27\lin\sitepackages` and renamed it to `...*.egg`. It worked.